# How to handle multiple envoirnment urls in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I am developing a polymer component which is using firebase polymer element inside it.
I have seperate URls for firebase in staging and production, so I want to know what is  the best design pattern to handle these environment urls in the polymer app.

Answer (score 0):

If it's one instance, can you just change the `location` to your staging URL?

For something more advanced (e.g. using a mock endpoint with all instances of `<firebase-element>` or testing), Scott put together an example of how to use `core-ajax` with mock data that may be useful: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/mock-ajax.